# Attaching source in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, spring

I wanted to walk through the spring code. For that I downloaded the Spring source, built it using Gradle. But now the issues is that for each spring .jar (i.e spring-aop, spring-sapects etc) I have to manually attach the jar.

Attaching each jar manually is very tedious. Is there any better solution to attach source. May be attaching the parent source folder for each .jar. My build folder looks like:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can put all your sources in one folder, and select all in the window provided, for that matter.

[image]

Comment: ' in the window provided'?, Don't know what do you mean by that.

Comment: The window comes when you press one of the Add buttons from properties window. I add a snapshot to illustrate what I meant. Sorry if I get your question wrong.

Comment: That will add only jars but for each jar i want to attach source and if number of jars are large, it will be very tedious to attach source for each jar